# What assumptions are require for convergence in probability or almost sure convergence here?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, inference

Let $H_1$ , $H_2$, . . . be sequence of independent Bernoulli coin tosses, with
probability $p_n$, with $p_n$ → 0, as n → ∞, so that

$H_n$ = 1 with probability $p_n$
$H_n$ = 0 with probability $1-p_n$

Does $H_n$ converge in probability to 0? Does $H_n$ almost surely convergence to 0?

Make specific assumptions for $p_n$ for both, if necessary.

My attempt:
I have found that $H_n$ does converge in probability to 0, and does not almost surely converge to 0. However, what specific assumptions are required for these to hold?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need any assumptions to show convergence in probability beyond those already stated.

Whether you have almost sure convergence would be determined by whether the probabilities satisfy the condition of the Borel-Cantelli lemma. (By the second Borel-Cantelli lemma, this is both a necessary and sufficient condition, because your random variables are independent.)